# ENMTools_1.4.4.pl on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to get ENMTools_1.4.4.pl running on Ubuntu 15.04.

According to the docs I need Tk+ and Perl. How do I:
- Check the versions that i may already have?
- update/install the latest versions?
- launch the *.pl script?

I tried:
    /usr/bin/perl ./ENMTools_1.4.4.pl'

I currently get:

```
"Can't locate Tkx.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Tkx module) (
+@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl/5.20.2 /u
+sr/local/share/perl/5.20.2 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20 /usr/sh
+are/perl5 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl/5.20 /usr/share/perl/5.20 /usr
+/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./ENMTools.pl line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./ENMTools.pl line 7"
```

Any ideas?
Steve

Comment: did you read my answer on perlmonks? http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1166486

Comment: I believe this is off-topic for this site because it relates only to administration (albeit packages related to programming). You may consider asking to have this moved to a different SE site.

Comment: @stevieb I did see your comments. Noted and resolved thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@stevieb gave me the answer. I'll post it here as a matter of closure:

Perl seemed OK itself

1.4.4$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say Data::Dumper->VERSION'
2.151_01

Once I had installed cpanm I used:
cpanm Tkx

It opens and ENMTools seems to work